# Will the moss on the siding affect deck repainting in short term?

Tags: deck, mold, repainting, lumber, moss

I was told by some contractor that the moss (he thought there was mold as well) will transfer to the deck, and it should be cleaned by power wash before repainting the deck. However, my tenants don’t want us to power wash the house before they move out next year, but they are okay with deck repainting, and it seems I have to get the deck repaired and repainted before the winter. May I just clean the deck and paint? Will the moss on the siding affect deck repainting in short term, e.g. 1 year?

[image]

Comment: It's good to respect your tenants wishes - gets you credits as a good landlord. I don't know how long it'll be until they move out, but if it's soon, then just wait and do all the maintenance when they're gone. If it's going to be a while, let them know that this _has_ to be done as part of the repairs to the deck and work out a time that works well for both of you.

Comment: They will move out next summer, but it seems I have to get the deck repaired and repainted before the winter without the siding cleaned.

Answer (score 1):

That's not moss. It's [Artillery fungus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphaerobolus) or something similar (mold), and it's *everywhere*. Cleaning it off your siding will have no significant effect on your deck.

Comment: Thank you. If I do not clean it, may I repaint my deck now? I can clean it by power wash next summer.

Comment: Unless the fungus/mold is also on the deck, I don't see how it's going to impact cleaning/painting the deck in any way. If it _is_ on the deck, you'll _definitely_ want to clean it off the deck before painting, or you'll be repainting the deck again after they move out.

Comment: Yes, that was implied by my answer. Do whatever you want with the deck. The walls aren't a factor.